# why does Policy Analyzer gets File Builder Error when saving backups?

Tags: group-policy, gpo

I'm trying to execute Policy analyzer with exported backup files as did many times before but now get an error while trying to save the backups in policy analyzer.

The error is:

Policy Rules File Builder:
Invalid file format. Expected headers not found.

Does anyone have a solution?